# Snapkit LayoutConstraints Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, snapkit

I have simple UITableView and custom UITablViewCell in my project, which created programmatically and use SnapKit for auto layout its.
When I run app, everything work fine and get some LayoutConstraints error in debug console.

[image]

**UITableViewCell**

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    ...
    private lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var centerStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, disclosureImageView])
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 5.0
        return stackView
    }()
    
    private lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .semibold)
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var disclosureImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "disclosure")
        return imageView
    }()
    
   ..
    
    private func setupUI() {
        selectionStyle = .none
        backgroundColor = .background
        contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.addSubview(centerStackView)
        setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Update Constraints
    override func updateConstraints() {
        containerView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(8)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
            make.height.equalTo(100)
        }
        
        centerStackView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

How I can fix this constraint error ?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two conflicts for each table view cell. You can copy-paste the sets of constraints are in conflict into https://www.wtfautolayout.com and see exactly why they are conflicting. As a result, we get [this](https://www.wtfautolayout.com/?constraintlog=(%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CSnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x7b1800023d00@MyViewController.swift%2368%20UIView:0x7b4800007080.top%20%3D%3D%20UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b4c00003800.top%20%20%208.0%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CSnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x7b1800023ca0@MyViewController.swift%2368%20UIView:0x7b4800007080.bottom%20%3D%3D%20UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b4c00003800.bottom%20-%208.0%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CSnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x7b1800023d60@MyViewController.swift%2370%20UIView:0x7b4800007080.height%20%3D%3D%20100.0%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400031920%20%27UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height%27%20UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b4c00003800.height%20%3D%3D%20116.5%20%20%20(active)%3E%22%0A)) and [this](https://www.wtfautolayout.com/?constraintlog=(%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x7b14000300c0%20%27UISV-canvas-connection%27%20UIStackView:0x7b4c00001a40.leading%20%3D%3D%20UILabel:0x7b5800001200.leading%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400030610%20%27UISV-canvas-connection%27%20H:%5BUIImageView:0x7b5000071200%5D-(0)-%7C%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UIStackView:0x7b4c00001a40%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x7b14000306b0%20%27UISV-spacing%27%20H:%5BUILabel:0x7b5800001200%5D-(5)-%5BUIImageView:0x7b5000071200%5D%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x7b140000f780%20%27UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width%27%20UIStackView:0x7b4c00001a40.width%20%3D%3D%200%20%20%20(active)%3E%22%0A)).

We can see that the first conflict is caused by your container view having a height constraint, but the table view itself also adds a height constraint to the cell to enforce its cells' sizes,

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400031920 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b4c00003640.height == 116.5   (active)>"
```

For some reason, the constant here is 116.5, not 116 as you would expect from the 100 points of height of the container view + the 16 points of inset.

You can either change it to

```
make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(100)
```

Or remove the height constraint completely:

```
// make.height.equalTo(100)
```

and use the delegate method `heightForRowAt` to control the cell height instead:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    116
}
```

As for the second conflict, it is caused by a constraint constraining the stack view's width to 0, being in conflict with the fact that there must be  some spacing between the image and label.

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400031b50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIStackView:0x7b4c000039c0.width == 0   (active)>"
```

If you move the following code from `updateConstraints` into `setupUI`, the conflict is resolved:

```
containerView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
    make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(8)
    make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
    make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(100)
}

centerStackView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
    make.center.equalToSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can you tell me, I override function `updateConstraints()` for customization `UITableVIewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` instead `makeConstraints()`, is it incorrect way to setup constraints ?

Comment: @user3544668 I have never overridden `updateConstraints` for adding constraints for adding constraints to my views. As its name and the discussion in its documentation suggests, it's for updating existing constraints, not for setting things up, so I *don't think* this is correct... I've always just called `makeConstraints` and I've never encountered any problems regarding this.